# Why do we need to convert a zipped object into a list

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to complete a datacamp exercise in which I am required to convert 2 lists into a `zip object` and then into a `dict` to finally get a `dataframe` using pandas.

However, If I use `zip()` function over the lists and convert them into a dict and then to a dataframe I get no errors but simple a perfect looking dataframe.
But the instructions say that i must convert a zipped object into a list first and then convert it into a `dict()`.

I dont understand how that helps me because I get the same output each time. i.e a dataframe.
`I am using python3`

#### With `list()`

```
list_keys = ['Country', 'Total']
list_values = [['United States', 'Soviet Union', 'United Kingdom'], [1118, 473, 273]]

import pandas as pd

zipped = list(zip(list_keys,list_values))

# Inspect the list using print()
print(zipped)

# Build a dictionary with the zipped list: data
data = dict(zipped)

# Build and inspect a DataFrame from the dictionary: df
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

#### `output:`

```
[('Country', ['United States', 'Soviet Union', 'United Kingdom']), ('Total', [1118, 473, 273])]
          Country  Total
0   United States   1118
1    Soviet Union    473
2  United Kingdom    273
```

#### Without `list()`

```
zipped = zip(list_keys,list_values)

# Inspect the list using print()
print(zipped)

# Build a dictionary with the zipped list: data
data = dict(zipped)

# Build and inspect a DataFrame from the dictionary: df
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

#### `output:`

```
<zip object at 0x10c069648>
          Country  Total
0   United States   1118
1    Soviet Union    473
2  United Kingdom    273
```

Comment: Can you show us the instructions? There may be some context that you missed.

Comment: @user2357112 The instructions mentions the following:
 The zip() function in Python 3 and above returns a special zip object, which is essentially a generator. To convert this zip object into a list, you'll need to use list()

Comment: but essentially I am confused because I am able to get away from list conversion and still get a perfect dataframe.

Comment: Yeah, your understanding is correct. You do not have to call `list`, indeed, it is needlessly inefficient to do so.

Comment: I think secret is in `dict(zipped)` - it implicitly convert `zip object` or `list object` to `dictionary`. so here `list` is redundant.

Comment: You don't need to call `list` on the zip object just to pass the result to `dict`, but it's possible that they wanted you to do something else with the list that would justify its existence.

Comment: @jezrael I believe this is simply a case of poorly worded instructions. The point whoever wrote this was probably simply to point out that in Python 2, `zip` is equivalent to `list(zip(...))` but it wasn't meant as a suggestion to do that

Comment: cool! that really helps, I will learn more about them through the python documentation.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga - or comment above `print(zipped)` - `Inspect the list using print()` explain it :)

Comment: The main reasons to convert to a list are (1) you need to use the values over and over, not just once; (2) you need to read values by index or get the length; and (3) you need to print the values out for debugging purposes. If you don't need any of those (or anything else that sounds similar enough to worry you), don't bother calling `list`.

Answer (score 5):

I think `dict(zipped)` convert `zip object` or `list object` to `dictionary`. So here convert to `list` is redundant.

---

But if want create `DataFrame` from `zip` object in `python 3` it is problem, need convert to `list`s of `tuple`s first:

```
a = ['United States', 'Soviet Union', 'United Kingdom']
b = [1118, 473, 273]
c = ['Country', 'Total']

zipped = zip(a,b)
print(zipped)
<zip object at 0x000000000DC4E8C8>

df = pd.DataFrame(zipped, columns=c)
print(df)
TypeError: data argument can't be an iterator
```

---

```
print(list(zipped))
[('United States', 1118), ('Soviet Union', 473), ('United Kingdom', 273)]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zipped), columns=c)
print(df)

          Country  Total
0   United States   1118
1    Soviet Union    473
2  United Kingdom    273
```

Comment: well that also means, I dont need to convert the `zip` object into a `dict`. You just demonstrated i can simply convert it into a list and pass it to `pd.Dataframe`

Comment: @Shoaibkhanz - In your sample it is not necessary, because convert to `dict` and from `dict` to `dataFrame`. But I want show if it is necessary, because `zip` object cannot be used as input for `DataFrame` constuctor.